# Wondering how to go about creating a DataGrid View on Vb.net using text files

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a set of text files that I need to load into a table.  I think using DataGrid View would be easiest.  It is for a room booking system which the clients can modify then save back to the text file.  I read the components in the text file using stream reader and then split them up into temporary arrays.  How do I create multiple columns and rows using a DataGrid View

Comment: First, rethink your data storage.  Text files are not random access.  If a database is "too much" for now, you could use XML.  For that, you'd use a DataTable which would allow you to `ReadXML` to load the data, `WriteXML` to save the data and use the DataTable as a DataSource for the DGV

Answer (score 0):

You should use a class to store one row of your data. Each public property of the class will be displayed as one column of your  DataGridView. Store the objects in `List<T>`. This list will contain the "rows".

Place a `BindingSource` component on your form and choose the class as data source. Then assign the list to the `DataSource` property of the BindingSource.

This is explained in more detail here [DataGridView.DataSource Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource(v=vs.110).aspx)
and here [How to: Bind Objects to Windows Forms DataGridView Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0wfd4yz(v=vs.90).aspx). Note: you can do the binding work within the WinForms designer and don't need to code the bindings manually.

When using text files to store your data, you will very soon notice that this type of storage is not adequate. It is not dynamic, i.e. you cannot add, update or remove single records. You always have to read the whole file, make changes in memory and then write back all the data to the file. One more severe problem arises from the fact that your data is probably not flat, i.e. you will most likely have relations between different types of entities like customers, rooms and more. Databases allow you to model such relations. They allow you to query, update and delete single records. They allow you to run complex queries answering questions like, which room is free at a given time, which room is booked by which customer, how many times did a customer book a room, and many more. Use a database!